# SQL Left join with no id not returning

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I feel like I'm missing something simple here...

**Table A(Name, Value)**

```
ABC  123
DEF  456
XYZ  789
NON  111
```

**Table B(Name1, Name2, Color)**

```
ABC  NULL  Red
NULL DEF   Blue
```

SQL query

```
select * 
from TableA A
left join TableB B on A.name = B.name1 or A.name = B.name2
```

Doing this will only return

**A.name, a.value,  b.color**

```
ABC 123 Red
DEF 456 Blue
```

I need it to return

**A.name, a.value,  b.color**

```
ABC 123 Red
DEF 456 Blue
XYZ 789 NULL
NON 111 NULL
```

It's excluding rows in the left table.

Comment: Your query looks correct for the output you want.

Comment: Your code here looks correct. I'd check that you're actually using this code, and haven't got the tables swapped (joining from B to A), and that you are doing a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Checked your query. it works correctly on Mysql

Comment: Here is the SQL Fiddle that shows that the above works in SQL Server (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48d02/1).

Comment: Checked with SQL. Works just fine.

Comment: The example above does work but it's just an example of what I'm doing and what my output is when I do expect it to be like any other standard left join. It should not exclude rows on the left but it does and I have no WHERE clause either.

Comment: Then the example provided by you is insufficient to solve the problem. Please post the entire query with the table structure.  Please see the answer by @CodeByMoonlight.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment to the first answer says "I have some other tables being joined this is just a simplified example". I would guess that:

1) One of those tables is joined to TableB in your query
and 
2) This additional table is referred to in a WHERE clause
and
3) The relevant join is not a LEFT JOIN, and/or the WHERE clause is not accounting the NULL

These things will combine to negate the effect of your LEFT JOIN, such as in the example below:

```
select * 
from TableA A
left join TableB B on A.name = B.name1 or A.name = B.name2
left join TABLEC C ON b.Field1 = C.Field1
WHERE C.MyField = 'avalue'
```

Comment: I am joining on more tables but I only see the issue when joining on this table, I know it's difficult to diagnose it without seeing the actual query and data. When I comment out this join I get my expected and verified number of rows(96) when I do this left join I get 47. It's excluding any row in the left table that doesn't match the right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need all the entries in Table A joined with matching entries in Table B, you need a query like this -

```
SELECT 
     A.Name, 
     A.Value, 
     B.Color 
 FROM 
     TableA A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B 
         ON (A.Name B.Name1 OR A.Name = B.Name2)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. And here is some info for the OP - [difference between inner and outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/1636917)

Comment: So what's the difference between this and the OP's sample? The parentheses? Note that a `LEFT JOIN` is **the same** as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - the `OUTER` keyword is entirely optional.

Comment: I thought left outer join was the same as left join also

Comment: @Miguel-F I understand how the joins should work, I just don't understand why this left join doesn't work as it should but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the following query

```
select A.name, a.num, b.color 
from TableA A
left join TableB B on A.name = B.name1 or A.name = B.name2
```

it will get the result

```
ABC 123 Red
DEF 456 Blue
XYZ 789 NULL
NON 111 NULL
```